# Laravel configurable classes with multiple options

Tags: php, laravel, class

I've been using laravel now and then for about a year and I'm quite comfortable using it for various tasks I do daily.

Recently working on making a small mailing service for internal use at work and I like how I can specify in the configs which provider to use with the .env file and it seemingly switches depending on the settings I provide it in the .env

Made me question though how is this achieved so I could perhaps do something similar when playing around with it. Im comfortable making helpers which use custom libraries I've loaded in with composer but say I wanted to go up a level (in terms of my skills) and took a regular task like emailing and made some sort of class which has functions which carry out a task but in the background uses something someone specified in a config file and uses its picked library functions whilst still looking like a reusable function.

sorry for explaining it badly, I mean how like if you use Mail::send() it sends an email via the provider in the .env

heres a poor example of what I mean.

```
Foo::BasicMethod() --> the alias foo(the name for the everyday task) using its method.
```

BasicMethod() being a general method call meanwhile in the background I've got 3 composer libraries loaded in.

```
 1. FooLibrary
 2. CoolFoo
 3. 2FOO4U
```

Which ever I;ve set in a config file it uses that libraries methods when the BasicMethod() is called.

Comment: Not sure what your question is? As you seem to have answered it yourself :) Like you said, the different libraries use different underlying classes, but each have a wrapper class, which implement a certain Interface so the methods are the same (even though they probably differ in the base class). So switching between is seamless as each wrapper class adheres to the same interface specification so the method signatures are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Start with familiarizing yourself with a good understanding of service providers, facades and contracts.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/providers

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/facades

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/contracts

You'd want to create classes for each of the 3 libraries and have them implement a common contract (interface). This is how you switch between the libraries and use whichever is set in the configuration.

Consider an interface that has the following methods defined:

```
public function sendMail($to, $from, $message);

public function attachDocument($attachment);
```

By having each libraries wrapper class implement these methods, you can inject the correct implementation by binding the contract.

Next, you'd have a service provider that register's itself and bootstraps the class(es) along with the framework. Create a facade as a convenience mechanism for accessing the underlying class without having to actually expose it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. So essentially it’s about making each classe Adhere to one interface? Would I need to make custom classes to Adher to them if the libraries I’m using are already built? E.g I’ve got 2 different compression classes provided by 2 composer installs from github both have their own methods, I just write a custom class which ties their functions to the interface ?

Comment: Yeah exactly, you'd write wrapper classes that implement the interface, and under the hood of each one of those classes you use the library specific code. Then Laravel does the heavy lifting by resolving which one you set in the config via IoC. Most recently I did exactly this when building a voip calling system that used twilio and a couple other services.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, appreciate you taking the time to point to what I should read up on.

Comment: I've managed to warp my head around how to do this, quick question though if I make a Laravel package out of this how does the dependancies off my package work within laravel it self. e.g. My Package used 3 libraries which are loaded via composer, when ive packaged it up and make it accessible via composer will that cause an issue since it would be inside Laravels vendor folder and within my package there would be another vendor folder..... if you catch my drift?

Comment: That won't be a problem as you don't ship the vendor directory with your package. Composer will handle the dependency management and install what's needed. Your package will contain things like compiled assets, i.e. scripts, stylesheets, translations, etc. and of course your source code. Same idea as committing to source control. Rarely do people commit their dependencies, instead rely on package.json and package.lock to ensure the correct dependencies can be downloaded by others. NPM does this too.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanations, I was a bit worried about my dependancies being in the package when included in another project. A colleague told me when it reads my package.json if I need XYZ it will handle including them into the project as a whole not just for my files